# NDSolveValue result contradicts initial condition

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm trying to solve the Schroedinger equation in a box with two holes defined by:

```
l = 10.0;
th = 0.1;

rg = 
    RegionDifference[
        RegionDifference[
            RegionDifference[
                Rectangle[{-l , -l} , {l , l}] , 
                Rectangle[{-th , -0.5} , {th , 0.5}]
            ],
            Rectangle[{-th , 0.6} , {th , l + 0.9}]
        ],
        Rectangle[{-th , -0.6} , {th , -l-0.9}]
    ];
```

the region looks like this:
[image]

The numerical solution is obtained using:

```
schEq = I D[psi[x , y , t] , {t , 1}] + 
    1/2 Laplacian[psi[x , y , t] , {x , y}] == 0;
ic = psi[x, y , 0] == 10.0 Exp[-2 ((x + 5.0)^2 + y^2)];

sol = NDSolveValue[
   {
    schEq,
    ic,
    DirichletCondition[psi[x , y , t] == 0 , True]
    },
   psi,
   {x , y} \[Element] rg , {t , 0 , 0.1}];
```

This executes without problems, however:

```
sol[-5.0 , 0.0 , 0.0]
```

evaluates to `8.80568` instead of 10. This seems to contradict the initial conditions. Why is this value different from 10?

Comment: What is your Mathematica version? v12.2 can't reproduce your results

Comment: MMA 13.3 reproduces this result!

Comment: Note:  on MM 13.1 (MacOS, M1 chip) the region creation fails with the code given.  However, `rg = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-l, -l}, {l, l}], RegionUnion[Rectangle[{-th, -0.5}, {th, 0.5}], Rectangle[{-th, 0.6}, {th, l + 0.9}], Rectangle[{-th, -l - 0.9}, {th, -0.6}]]];` gives the same region and works fine.

Comment: Hi, using Mathematica 13.3 on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at the mesh that is automatically generated:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[rg]
```

Now, we evaluate the ic at the coordinates of that default mesh:

```
data = Function[{x, y}, 10. E^(-2 ((5.` + x)^2 + y^2))] @@@ 
   mesh["Coordinates"];
```

Looking at the MinMax we get:

```
MinMax[data]
(* {5.11195*10^-282, 9.22845} *)
```

So, we see that the larges value is not even 10. For the interpolation of the values you will always need several values close by - those are even smaller such that we do not get to the value of 10. That's just how interpolation works.

One thing you could do is add a mesh coordinate that `{-5,0}`.

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[rg, "IncludePoints" -> {{-5, 0}}];
data = Function[{x, y}, 10. E^(-2 ((5.` + x)^2 + y^2))] @@@ 
   mesh["Coordinates"];
MinMax[data]
(* {5.11195*10^-282, 10.} *)
```

But what you really want is a finer then the default mesh:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[rg, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.05];
sol = NDSolveValue[{schEq, ic, 
    DirichletCondition[psi[x, y, t] == 0, True]}, 
   psi, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, {t, 0, 0.1}];
sol[-5.0, 0.0, 0.0]
(* 9.99076 - 4.42003*10^-18 I *)
```

Comment: It's also instructive to superimpose the contour for which the initial wave function is equal to 9 on top of the mesh:  `Show[MeshRegion[mesh], ContourPlot[ic[[2]] == 9, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, ContourStyle -> Red]]` On my machine there's *maybe* one mesh point inside this contour.  This also shows why the finer mesh helps resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you everyone! This was very instructive. I'm thinking of diving a little deeper into PDEs in Mathematica. Is the electronic documentation a good resource?

Comment: Good question: but my opinion might be slightly biased - as I wrote substantial parts of the FEM/PDEModeling stuff ;-) but seriously, if find things that are not clear, let me know and I'll see if I can explain them better.